# Apex set value of 0 always results in 1

Tags: apex

I'm working on a wrapper class that loops through a table of opportunities and updates/creates them accordingly. I'm running into an issue where I set the values in the wrapper class VF page but when I save it out it always sets a 0 value to 1. The specific line of code is ***wrapper.opp.Units__c = 0;***.

I think it has to do with how I am working with primitive data types but it would seem to me that if I set something as zero then it should populate as zero.

Let me know if anything else is needed. See code below.

```
public class OpportunityBrandWinListEditController {

// wrapper classes for the contacts being managed
public List<OpportunityBrandWinWrapper> wrappers {get; set;}

// when a user chooses to add items, the number of
// items to add will be present in this property
public Integer addItemCount {get; set;}

// when a user deletes a record, the record key will
// be present in this property
public Integer keyToDelete {get; set;}

// the unique record key master value
public Integer mainKey {get; set;}

public Date nextCloseDate {get; set;}

// the records to delete when the user saves their work
private List<Opportunity> toDelete=new List<Opportunity>();

//parameters passed - wga
public String bwOppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('bwOppId');

//get Brand Win opp and first Forecast Opp
public Opportunity bwOpp = [Select MRRPerUnit__c,
                            ID,
                            Account.Name,
                            AccountId,
                            Brand__c
                            From Opportunity
                            Where ID =:bwOppId];

public Opportunity firstForecastOpp = [Select MRRPerUnit__c, 
                                       ID, 
                                       Account.Name, 
                                       AccountId, 
                                       Brand__c, 
                                       Type, 
                                       CloseDate,
                                       MatchonFlow__c,
                                       CreatedFromFlow__c
                                       From Opportunity 
                                       Where RelatedDesignWin__c =:bwOppId 
                                       Order by CloseDate ASC 
                                       Limit 1];

//set a double to hold numbers
public Double totalUnits = 0;
public Double remainingUnits = 0;

// constructor
public OpportunityBrandWinListEditController()
{
    mainKey=1;
    addItemCount=1;
    wrappers=new List<OpportunityBrandWinWrapper>();

    // get the first five contacts from the database to ensure there is some data present on the page
    List<Opportunity> opps = [select id, 
                              CloseDate, 
                              Total_MRR__c, 
                              Units__c,
                              Total_NRR__c,
                              RelatedDesignWin__r.ForecastedUnits__c,
                              RelatedDesignWin__r.MRRPerUnit__c,
                              ForecastedUnits__c,
                              CumulativeForecast__c,
                              DiscreteExpectedUnits__c,
                              DiscreteTotalUnits__c,
                              Expected_Units__c,
                              Name,
                              Account.Name
                              from Opportunity
                              WHERE RelatedDesignWin__c =: bwOppId 
                              order by CloseDate ASC];

    for (Opportunity opp : opps)
    {
        wrappers.add(new OpportunityBrandWinWrapper(mainKey++, opp));
    }
}

// add a number of items to the list
public PageReference addItems()
{
    if ( (addItemCount>0) && (addItemCount<10) )
    {
        for (Integer idx=0; idx<addItemCount; idx++)
        {
            wrappers.add(new OpportunityBrandWinWrapper(mainKey++, new Opportunity(DiscreteExpectedUnits__c = 0)));
        }
    }

    return null;
}

// save the users work
public PageReference save()
{
    PageReference result = null;
    Boolean error = false;
    List<Opportunity> toUpsert = new List<Opportunity>();

    for (OpportunityBrandWinWrapper wrapper : wrappers)
    {

            {
                if((wrapper.opp.ForecastedUnits__c - wrapper.opp.DiscreteExpectedUnits__c - remainingUnits) <= 0){
                    *wrapper.opp.Units__c = 0;*
                    wrapper.opp.Total_MRR__c = 0;
                    remainingUnits = Math.abs(wrapper.opp.ForecastedUnits__c - wrapper.opp.DiscreteExpectedUnits__c - remainingUnits);
                }
                else {
                    wrapper.opp.Units__c = (wrapper.opp.ForecastedUnits__c - wrapper.opp.DiscreteExpectedUnits__c - remainingUnits);
                    wrapper.opp.Total_MRR__c = (wrapper.opp.ForecastedUnits__c - wrapper.opp.DiscreteExpectedUnits__c - remainingUnits) *  bwOpp.MRRPerUnit__c;
                    remainingUnits = 0;
                }
                wrapper.opp.RelatedDesignWin__c = bwOppId;
                wrapper.opp.StageName = 'Commitment';
                wrapper.opp.Total_NRR__c = 0;
                wrapper.opp.AccountId = bwOpp.AccountId;
                wrapper.opp.Brand__c =  bwOpp.Brand__c;
                wrapper.opp.CreatedFromFlow__c = firstForecastOpp.CreatedFromFlow__c;
                wrapper.opp.MatchonFlow__c = firstForecastOpp.MatchonFlow__c;
                wrapper.opp.Type = firstForecastOpp.Type;
                wrapper.opp.Description = String.ValueOf(wrapper.opp.Units__c);
                wrapper.opp.CloseDate = firstForecastOpp.CloseDate.addMonths(((wrapper.key-1)*3)+1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1);
                wrapper.opp.Name = bwOpp.Account.Name + ' > Q' + wrapper.opp.CloseDate.month()/3 + ' ' + wrapper.opp.CloseDate.year();
                totalUnits = wrapper.opp.Units__c++;
                wrapper.opp.CumulativeForecast__c = totalUnits;

                toUpsert.add(wrapper.opp);
            }

    }

    if (!error)
    {
        upsert toUpsert;

        // return the user to the contacts tab
        result=new PageReference('/' + bwOppId);
    }

    return result;
} 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your issue is this line:

```
totalUnits = wrapper.opp.Units__c++;
```

The post increment is assigning the value of `wrapper.opp.Units__c` result to `totalUnits` and then incrementing it by 1.

Presumably you just want:

```
totalUnits = wrapper.opp.Units__c;
```

But if `totalUnits` should be one higher then do:

```
totalUnits = wrapper.opp.Units__c + 1;
```

Comment: and if you want both to be incremented: `totalUnits = ++wrapper.opp.Units__c;`